# React Native - call restful API synchronously

Tags: android, api, react-native, synchronization, restful-url

I know that React Native uses JS way of doing things ie making function calls asynchronous. So this also applies to API "fetch" function. However, for some reason, I need to make API "fetch" synchronous.

This is what I want to do. The app has a listing of items. It has to loop through the items and for each of them, I need to construct the URL and then call "fetch" based on constructed URL to get the response (eg if I have 5 items, it would call the API 5 times, where each URL called has different parameters). Once I have successfully received responses for all of the listing items, then I need to do something else, such as updating some state (the state is dependent on having all of the responses returned).

Note that I have no control over the backend ie unable to change the URL side to have batch calls instead.

Question is, how do I make sync call in React Native?

Comment: you may not need to call apis synchronously. If you just want to do something after getting data from all the api calls then you can use Promise.all() https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all. It will resolve when all the promises are resolved and you will get an array of results in its ".then()" function

Answer (score 0):

You can call synchronously by using XMLHttpRequest object.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://mywebsite.com/endpoint.php', false); // third parameter  FALSE makes Synchronous HTTP request
request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

or

you will get many npm modules that will provide synchronous api call.

i hope this will help you.

Comment: [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Synchronous http requests are not supported]